# For loop else if statement is not evaluating

Tags: c++

I have a function that iterates through the contents of a map, and prints the key if it finds a matched value.

```
void returnFriendlyName(int input)
{
    std::map<std::string, int>::iterator it;

    for (it = friendlyName_id.begin(); it != friendlyName_id.end(); it++)
        if (it->second == input)
            std::cout << '\n' << "The Friendly Name for id:" << input << " is " << it->first << '\n' << '\n';
        else if (it == friendlyName_id.end())
            std::cout << "Sorry, that id does not exist.";
}
```

However, the **else if** statement isn't evaluating if I supply an input that does not match a value in the map.

This is confusing for me because my understanding of the loop is as follows when the input does not match a value:

1. **it** is initialized
2. **it** is tested against a condition
3. **it** is incremented if condition is true
4. **it** is eventually incremented to **friendlyName_id.end()** prior to the **for** condition being evaluated again
5. the **else if** statement should now be evaluated

Is my understanding of this code incorrect? Am I missing something that is causing the **else if** to not evaluate?

**Edit**

Maybe I worded my question poorly. What I'm looking to do is output an error message in the event that my function iterates through the entire map without a match.

But I don't want to output that error message *each time* the input is checked for a match.

I was trying to write an `else` or `else if` statement that executes once only if there is no match in the map

Comment: If the loop body was run with `it == end()`, your `if` statement would blow up - it is dereferencing `it`, which you can't do if it's at the end.

Comment: You have this condition in your loop: `it != friendlyName_id.end()` so how could `it == friendlyName_id.end()` ever be true inside it?

Comment: Your understanding is not correct. The afterthought (in your case, iterator incrementation) is run after the loop body is executed, not immediately after condition check

Comment: #1 and #2 are correct, #3 is incorrect, #4/#5 I have no idea what you're trying to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever your `it` reach the `friendlyName_id.end()` the loop is over (by the loop's condition), and you will never reach this part inside your loop.

```
void returnFriendlyName(int input)
{
    std::map<std::string, int>::iterator it;

    for (it = friendlyName_id.begin(); it != friendlyName_id.end(); it++) {
        if (it->second == input) {
            std::cout << '\n' << "The Friendly Name for id:" << input << " is " << it->first << '\n' << '\n';
            break;
        }
    }
    if (it == friendlyName_id.end()) std::cout << "Sorry, that id does not exist.";
}
```

One more thing, pay attention that your function's name is `returnFriendlyName` which means to return a value you can continue the work with, and here all you do is to print this (probably important) information. To change this, change the function's signature:

```
void returnFriendlyName(int input)
```

To something like:

```
string returnFriendlyName(int input)
```

And add a return statement (or statements):

```
string returnFriendlyName(int input)
{
    std::map<std::string, int>::iterator it;
    string result = "not-found";

    for (it = friendlyName_id.begin(); it != friendlyName_id.end(); it++) {
        if (it->second == input) {
            std::cout << '\n' << "The Friendly Name for id:" << input << " is " << it->first << '\n' << '\n';
            result = it->first;
            break; // return result;
        }
    }
    if (it == friendlyName_id.end()) // Unnecessary condition if you used the return statement instead of the `break` inside the loop, because in this case you won't reach this part of the function if the element exists in the list.
        std::cout << "Sorry, that id does not exist.";
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, adding ```break``` and splitting it up into two ```if``` statements worked.

Comment: @RyanOliverLanham pay attention to the edit, I think it might help you in your next step :)

Answer (score 1):

> Is my understanding of this code incorrect? Am I missing something that is causing the else if to not evaluate?

Yes, it is incorrect. The `else` clause is for the `if`, not for the `for`.

You may be confused by the `else` clauses of other languages, like Python's.

If you add braces, you will see it clearly. This is equivalent:

```
void returnFriendlyName(int input)
{
    std::map<std::string, int>::iterator it;

    for (it = friendlyName_id.begin(); it != friendlyName_id.end(); it++) {
        if (it->second == input)
            std::cout << '\n' << "The Friendly Name for id:" << input << " is " << it->first << '\n' << '\n';
        else if (it == friendlyName_id.end())
            std::cout << "Sorry, that id does not exist.";
    }
}
```

The order is:

1. **it** is initialized
2. **it** is tested against the loop condition. If false, quit.
3. The body of the loop runs, which includes the `if` and the `else if`.
4. **it** is incremented
5. Jump back to 2